# How can I make a button that sends information and closes on release?

Tags: java, swing

I have no experience with GUI so I'm just noodling around and going crazy trying to figure things out. What I have now is when I push I button, another window pops up with a combo box with names and a button that closes the window and sends back the selected choice to the main window.
I can't seem to get the window to become invisible or how to send information back to my original window (library_GUI)

```
        JComboBox nameBox = new JComboBox(names.toArray());
    contentPane.add(nameBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    String nam = (String)nameBox.getSelectedItem();
    JButton checkOutButton = new JButton("Check Out");
    checkOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFrame.setVisible(false);
        }
```

Comment: In my opinion, the window pops up is a instance of JDialog, instead of JFrame.

Comment: Use a modal dialog as the second window such as a JOptionPane or a JDialog. Then simply have the first class query the combobox after the dialog returns.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a demo for you, check if it meets your requirement.

```
public class JDialogDemo
{
    public JDialogDemo()
    {   
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("mainWindow");
    mainWindow.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 300);
    mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JDialog dlg = new JDialog(mainWindow, true);
    dlg.setBounds(300, 300, 200, 100);
    final JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new String[]{"A", "B"});
    JButton okBtn = new JButton("Ok");
    okBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object item = box.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(item);
            dlg.setVisible(false);
        }

    });
    dlg.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    dlg.getContentPane().add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    dlg.getContentPane().add(okBtn, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton popupBtn = new JButton("Popup");
    popupBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            dlg.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
    mainWindow.getContentPane().add(popupBtn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new JDialogDemo();
}
}
```

good luck, have fun.

Comment: 1+ for the effort.  Now just add a little code showing the calling window extracting and displaying the data obtained in the dialog.